# Rails does not transition out from daylight savings time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone

Rails ver: `6.0.3.4`
Ruby ver: `2.6.6`
tzinfo gem ver: `1.2.7`

Although daylight switching was supposed to end on Nov 1st, my rails application is somehow still using PDT (`-7:00`) when I expect it to be in PST (`-08:00`) on Nov 4th.

```
> Time.now
2020-11-05 02:45:15 +0000
> Time.zone.now
Wed, 04 Nov 2020 19:45:23 PDT -07:00
```

Here's what I know so far:

- OS's `/etc/localtime` is set to correct GMT
- `config.time_zone` is set to `Pacific Time (US & Canada)`
- `config.active_record.default_timezone` isn't set
- Postgres is set to UTC

Anyone know what's going on? I noticed that `Time.zone.tzinfo.current_period` is a little odd (set to 2007) but not sure if it's relevant:

```
> Time.zone.tzinfo.current_period
#<TZInfo::TimezonePeriod: #<TZInfo::TimezoneTransitionDefinition: #<TZInfo::TimeOrDateTime: 1173607200>,#<TZInfo::TimezoneOffset: -28800,3600,PDT>>,nil>
> Time.zone.tzinfo.current_period.local_start
Sun, 11 Mar 2007 03:00:00 +0000
> Time.zone.tzinfo.current_period.local_end
nil
```

Update: Here are the zdump info, so looks like OS has the right info:

```
> zdump -v /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles | grep 2020
/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles  Sun Mar  8 09:59:59 2020 UT = Sun Mar  8 01:59:59 2020 PST isdst=0 gmtoff=-28800
/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles  Sun Mar  8 10:00:00 2020 UT = Sun Mar  8 03:00:00 2020 PDT isdst=1 gmtoff=-25200
/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles  Sun Nov  1 08:59:59 2020 UT = Sun Nov  1 01:59:59 2020 PDT isdst=1 gmtoff=-25200
/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles  Sun Nov  1 09:00:00 2020 UT = Sun Nov  1 01:00:00 2020 PST isdst=0 gmtoff=-28800
```

More `TZInfo`:

```
> TZInfo::DataSource.get
#<TZInfo::ZoneinfoDataSource: /usr/share/zoneinfo>
```

Comment: Yes, that current_period is incorrect. `local_start` should be Nov 1, 2020 and local_end should be March 14, 2021.

Comment: March 11, 2007 coincides with the most recent national change to DST in the US.

Comment: Good to know! Just added zdump data to the question

Comment: What does `TZInfo::DataSource.get` say? See [TZInfo - Data Sources](https://github.com/tzinfo/tzinfo#data-sources).

Comment: Just updated the q to include it!

Comment: I'm stumped. If you make a fresh Rails app with `rails new` does it have the same problem? This will narrow down if it's Ruby/Rails or your OS.

Comment: Ah im running this within `ruby:2.6.6-alpine` image on AMI machine through ECS. Don't have the write access when I'm executing these commands with `docker exec` from a live container :/

Comment: Hmm looks like there has been some issue with the latest tz file
https://github.com/tzinfo/tzinfo/issues/120

Comment: Ok looks like this rails issue!
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/40427

Comment: Its a tzinfo issue. https://github.com/tzinfo/tzinfo/issues/120 Fascinating! Work arounds in the issue. You should self-answer this, it will be of use to others. Great sleuthing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was due to tzinfo gem's incompatibility with the new tz version: https://github.com/tzinfo/tzinfo/issues/120

> The 2020b version of the 'zic' time zone compiler has changed to output zoneinfo files using a new 'slim' format by default. The slim format requires users of the zoneinfo files to interpret rules instead of just reading a list of transitions.
>
> TZInfo currently only supports reading the transitions and will require modification to use the rules. Consequently, it'll produce the wrong offset at some point after the final transition in the file.

The issue starts from the `2020b` format. `ruby:2.6-alpine` installs `2020c` by default when you run `apk add tzdata`

```
> docker run -it alpine:3.12
/ > apk add tzdata && apk list | grep tzdata
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.12/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.12/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/1) Installing tzdata (2020c-r0)
Executing busybox-1.31.1-r19.trigger
OK: 9 MiB in 15 packages
tzdata-2020c-r0 x86_64 {tzdata} (Public-Domain) [installed]
tzdata-doc-2020c-r0 x86_64 {tzdata} (Public-Domain)
```